# Envio a traves de SendMail usando PHPMailer

Tags: phpmailer

Buenas tardes, estoy tratando de realizar envios por email haciendo uso de la libreria PHPMailer a traves de un correo de Sendmail. La configuración me ha funcionado con exito conectando con el smtp de Gmail, pero al momento de realizar la conexion al correo de sendmail da fallo. Adjunto el codigo:

```
<?php 

session_start();

include_once('clases/class.phpmailer.php');
include_once('clases/class.smtp.php');


EnvioMensaje($_POST['id'],$_POST['name_comer'],$_POST['eml_usr'],  $_POST['eml_pas'], $_POST['eml_srv_smtp'], $_POST['eml_pue'], $_POST['eml_env'],  $_POST['eml_cit_body']);


function EnvioMensaje($id, $nom_comer, $mail_user, $mail_pass, $mail_smtp, $mail_port, $mail_env,$mail_body){


    $asunto = 'Recordatorio de Cita';
    $destino = $mail_env;
    $mensaje = $mail_body;

        $mail = new  PHPMailer();
        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
        $mail->Host = $mail_smtp;
        $mail->Port = $mail_port;

        $mail->Username = $mail_user;
        $mail->Password = $mail_pass;

        $mail->AddAddress($destino);
        $mail->Subject = $asunto;
        $mail->MsgHTML($mensaje);


        if($mail->Send()){

            echo 'Enviado con exito';

        }else
            {
            print_r($mail);
            echo 'No enviado';
            }






}


?>
```

He probado diversas configuraciones pero todas han dado errores. Agradeceria cualquier ayuda.

Adjunto una captura del fallo que se produce al intentar enviar el mensaje:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ya intentaste cambiar el SSL por TLS

Comment: _He probado diversas configuraciones pero todas han dado errores._ Eso, eso, **¿qué errores?**